# How to add PWA to Vue.js 3 app not created with Vue CLI?

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, vuejs3, workbox-webpack-plugin

I understand that the go-to plugin to enable PWA on Vue.js is [`@vue/cli-plugin-pwa`](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/pwa.html), however this seems to be for projects that were created using `vue-cli` and its version of Webpack + Workbox.

I have a `Vue.js 3` app that is being made without using `vue-cli`. That is, the project was created from scratch with `Webpack 5` being installed separately.

Do I still use `vue add pwa` from `vue-cli` to enable PWA on this app, or do I have to add it manually step-by-step using a guide like [this one](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/workbox-lab#0)?

Answer (score 2):

You can add PWA in any project with Workbox CLI tool.

Install Workbox CLI globally:

```sh
npm install workbox-cli --global
```

Setup the workbox in your distribution (dist) folder using the wizard.

```sh
workbox wizard
```

Add the service worker in your main entry point html file (index.html).

```html
  <script defer="defer">
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
```

Build the Vue project and then build the workbox pwa by running:

```sh
workbox generateSW workbox-config.js
```

And you are done!

Note: to automate the build process add the following script in your package.json file.

```json
    "build:pwa": "vue-cli-service build && workbox generateSW workbox-config.js",
```

Now you can build the project with pwa using:

```sh
npm run build:pwa
```

Learn more about [Workbox CLI](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-cli).